# Port android 4.2

Tags: port, android-4.2-jelly-bean, rom

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 HD LTE (Model: SHV-E120S).

Now there are very few ROMS out there for this device.

I was wondering if I could port Android 4.2 JB for my device....and I wanted to know how to get a start with this thing...

I have older versions of CM10 though...but as far as I know I cannot use that as my base ROM...

I want to understand how to port a rom when you don't have a base rom.

Even if someone can point me to something that will be great...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with **tegrak** and go for custom **ROM**. As per my knowledge there is no any custom **ROM** for the **shv e120s** after 4.1.2. If you find it, !!! it's really good. because I am trying for 4.2.2 **ROM** and 4.3 **ROM**. I got information from my friend, who is working in samsung technical department. 4.3 official is going to come for **shv e120s** soon. so wait for official.

Comment: Hey Gaurav, I have found a Mokee rom that is based on 4.2.2. It is quite stable and fast too. But the camera app is not working at its best and that is the reason i have removed it.